# How to know if a user clicked play on a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-embedding

I do not even know where to start with this but what I want to do is I want to be able to know if someone has clicked play on a video on my site. The code for the video embed is:

```
<div class="gv-placement-sap" id="gv_target_7196907613889253931538584">
</div>

<script>!function(a,b,c){var d=a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];a.getElementById(c)||(a=a.createElement(b),a.id=c,a.src=("https:"==document.location.protocol?"http://player-services.goviral-content.com".replace(/^http\:/,"https:"):"http://player-services.goviral-content.com")+"/embed-code/index/find?placementVersionId=7196907613889253931538584",d.parentNode.insertBefore(a,d))}(document,"script","gv_script_7196907613889253931538584");</script>
```

Any help is appreciated..thanks

Comment: Is there any callback in your JS script?

Comment: no, the provided code is all there is

Comment: Infact the whole JS file seems to be here: http://player-services.goviral-content.com/embed-code/index/find?placementVersionId=7196907613889253931538584

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but maybe try something like this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide